# Getting data out of SAP information box with vba

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I'm automating a process with VBA, and I'm using SAP Scripting to do so.

The process is basically go to VA01, input the Orders Data and save the order.
But there is a variant in saving the order that is cracking up my head.
The SAP displays a popup message with relevant informations about the order, and I need that information and can't figure out how to get the Text out of the infobox that is displaying when you save the order.

Infos are: Blocked on price, No limit etc... And when it displays that message, I need to save it on a TXT file (i've already got a code for that), I just need a help in manage how to get that text out of the infobox.

[image: Information Box]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you had an access to the messages you can use MESSAGE - INTO ([check info about it](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapmessage_into.htm))

if i got your task incorrect pls write here. Good luck

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I managed to do what i wanted with this code session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/txtMESSTXT1").Text

Comment: @zanniboni Please do not vote or mark correct an answer which is not useful, as per Stack Overflow rules. Instead, you may thank the person for his help, and edit your question to clarify it, like removing [tag:abap] which is irrelevant, and add [tag:sap-gui]. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduce here the [answer of the OP (@zanniboni)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51633680/getting-data-out-of-sap-information-box-with-vba/65447858?noredirect=1#comment90236096_51634516):

> "Hey, thanks for your help. I managed to do what I wanted with this code `session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/txtMESSTXT1").Text`".